# Kashering non-Kosher meat + "minimizing a transgression"

Tags: kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization, blood

Halacha has a strong tradition of "minimizing a transgression" when doing something forbidden, for example taking the shortest route possible when driving on the Sabbath.

Applying the same logic, suppose you were to purchase a cut of non-kosher slaughtered beef that would be kosher had it been properly slaughteted, and you soaked it, salted it and washed it as we are commanded to do, and ate it yourself (without offering it to anyone else). It would, of course, still be treif.

But would you be "minimizing your transgression" of eating non-kosher beef vs. eating that same treif piece of meat without having kashered it, or commiting another transgression entirely?

Comment: Somewhat similar concept in fiction, http://jewishstudies.rutgers.edu/docman/sinkoff/481-fiction-s-archive-authenticity-ethnography-and-philosemitism-in-john-hersey-s-the-wall/file discussion starts on page 60

Comment: Do you have a source for minimizing a transgression when possible? I know we do that when it comes to saving a life on Shabbos, we still try to do less, but to minimize it when doing something on purpose for no good reason?

Comment: @abochur why would we not? Also we can say this is a case of needing food on Yom Kippur and move on to the interesting part of the question

Comment: This responsum on inviting non-observant guests who may drive to shabbat dinner quotes Rabbi Akiva Eiger (Yoreh Deah 281:6) as advocating, in the case of a man who is determined to shave his temples, to have a woman (who is under no biblical prohibition from doing so) shave his temples for him in order to mimimize the transgression, @ABochur, my Aramaic is nowhere near where it would need to be to parse out the text in the original https://eng.beithillel.org.il/responsa/inviting-guest-who-drives-sabbath-holiday-meal/

Comment: @rosends I don't think that example is similar.  Removing the blood from non kosher beef or even from a horse actually accomplishes something.  Shechting a horse does not.  (Not even to remove tumas neveilah, if I'm remembering correctly.)

Comment: i just want to point out that sometimes when one convinces themselves that they are minimizing the transgression it is because they believe that they cannot put up with their evil inclination, which is a big mistake. I believe that there is an argument to be made for not   trying to minimize the transgression this way a person will not fool themselves into thinking that they are ok. I am drawing from a concept found in hilchot teshuva, that when a person does not understand the severity of the transgression they will not come to repent...

Comment: @DoubleAA Sometimes we purposely don't minimize transgression, as in the case of tevilah for a penuyah.

Comment: @ln65 that's not true. We don't tell her to have sex without Mikvah. We discourage mikvah in the hope that that discourages sex. A penuya who will have sex anyway should of course go to the Mikvah. Both those actions would be _independently_ without rabbinic approval.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are asking if _blood from Neveila_ is a separate prohibition from _Neveilah-meat_?

Comment: Yes, @DannySchoemann, and, separately from that, if there is a prohibition on removing the blood from *nevilah* meat

Answer (score 1):

The part of soaking, salting and washing it removes the blood, so that would indeed minimize the transgression, since it removes the prohibition of eating blood. but slaughtering it does nothing to minimize the transgression because a kosher slaughtering only affects kosher animals.